# JSON Web Token in Node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, json-web-token

How can I alter the length of the JSON Web token that is generated from the usual jwt.sign(user,key) method?
I have currently set the key as simple "12345", but the token that is getting generated is very long. 
I am using passport-local-mongoose module package of the node js library for this.

[image: This is the token that is getting generated]

The secret key being used is : 
[image: Secret Key]

How can I shorten the token value?

Answer (score 1):

The token length depends on the data that you store inside your token. You can store user-related data and other stuff, which is just encoded and appended.

A JWT consists of three parts: **Header - Payload - Signature**
Those are separated using dots (.). The header stores data about the algorithm and necessary stuff while the signature is used to check that the data in the payload has not been modified. The data itself depends on you.

So to shorten the token, use less data to generate it. The secret has nothing to do with the length.

Comment: The data is just the username and password of the user registering. I dont think there are options to shorten that

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the value by removing the password from the payload.

Having it in the payload is not useful to you anyway:

> Tokens are signed to protect against manipulation, they are not encrypted. What this means is that **a token can be easily decoded and its contents revealed.** If we navigate over the jwt.io, and paste the above token, we’ll be able to read the header and payload – but without the correct secret, the token is useless and we see the message “Invalid Signature.”

https://auth0.com/learn/token-based-authentication-made-easy/